# why is this postgresql query returning only zeros?

Tags: postgresql, subquery

```
select g.ad_id, count(1) as total,
(select count(1) from geoData g1 WHERE g1.ad_id=g.ad_id and 
utc_timestamp > '2017-11-01 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-01 23:59:59') NOV1,
(select count(1) from geodata g2 where g2.ad_id=g.ad_id and 
utc_timestamp > '2017-11-02 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-02 23:59:59') NOV2,
(select count(1) from geodata g3 where g3.ad_id=g.ad_id and 
utc_timestamp > '2017-11-03 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-03 23:59:59') NOV3,
(select count(1) from geodata g4 where g4.ad_id=g.ad_id and 
utc_timestamp > '2017-11-04 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-04 23:59:59') NOV4,
(select count(1) from geodata g5 where g5.ad_id=g.ad_id and 
utc_timestamp > '2017-11-05 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-05 23:59:59') NOV5,
(select count(1) from geodata g6 where g6.ad_id=g.ad_id and 
utc_timestamp > '2017-11-06 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-06 23:59:59') NOV6,
(select count(1) from geodata g7 where g7.ad_id=g.ad_id and 
utc_timestamp > '2017-11-07 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-07 23:59:59') NOV7,
(select count(1) from geodata g8 where g8.ad_id=g.ad_id and 
utc_timestamp > '2017-11-08 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-08 23:59:59') NOV8,
(select count(1) from geodata g9 where g9.ad_id=g.ad_id and 
utc_timestamp > '2017-11-09 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-09 23:59:59') NOV9
FROM geoData g
group by g.ad_id ;
```

The psql says its ok, it takes almost an hour to run (it's 35gigs of data in the table) but it returns all zeros in the subqueries

Comment: Because you didn't qualify column names in the subqueries, may be?

Comment: Show the table definition and  some example data that you think should result in non-zero results.

Answer (score 0):

You know you don't need to use all those subqueries, right?

```
select g.ad_id, count(1) as total,
count(case when utc_timestamp > '2017-11-01 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-01 23:59:59' then 1 end) NOV1,
count(case when utc_timestamp > '2017-11-02 00:00:00' AND utc_timestamp < '2017-11-02 23:59:59' then 1 end) NOV2,
...
FROM geoData g
group by g.ad_id ;
```